# Extract a part of a data frame by selecting specific observations of a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
item_i  a   b   c
1   0   0   2
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
4   0.25    0   0.625
9   0.166666667 0   0.666666667
9   0.166666667 0   0.666666667
9   0   0   0.5
```

the rows i have are 1000 and item_i column has at least 20 different values. Lets say i want to extract the part of the data frame where item_i = 1,9,13,etc. By extract i mean that i also want columns a b and c. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I tried which((df$item_i) == c(1,9,13)

Comment: try `subset(df, item_i %in% c(1,9,13))`

Comment: Thanx mate that was what i was looking for!!!

Comment: Instead of only one restriction, can I also have more. For example subset(df, item_i %in% c(1,9,13) | week_i %in% c(1,2,3,4)

Comment: If i knew the subset function i would not have asked the same thing. I do not understand why i have to lose points for that. If someone has no clue about subset function my question is more suitable. delete the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose your data frame is called `DF` and you want item_i = 9, you coul try:

```
DF[DF$item_i==9,]
```

If you want item_i = 1 or 9 then

```
DF[DF$item_i %in% c(1,9),]
```

Comment: Thanx that also worked