# Multiple regression in R, how do I get rid of unknown value

Tags: r

Okay I am trying to build multiple regressions with R
And I am using the data from UsingR library -> babies
What I want to know is that according to the 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UsingR/UsingR.pdf
page.10, the unknown data gets the value something like 99 or 999.
So what I am trying to do is to get rid of the unknown data value (it depends but for wt1 is 999, and race is 9).
How should I show the summary m without including any unknown value?
The range of each element shows on the pdf file.

```
library(UsingR)
head(babies)

m <- lm(wt ~ gestation + age + wt1 + dage + dwt, data=babies)
summary(m)
```

Comment: You have to subset your dataframe. Similar to negating the condition in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721628/extract-a-part-of-a-data-frame-by-selecting-specific-observations-of-a-column-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that your missings are coded as 999 or 99?

You could try something like

```
babies$wt1[which(babies$wt1==999)]<-NA
```

and repeat and adjust it for the other variables. If you repeat the analysis it should do the complete cases analysis.

Answer (score -3):

```
na.omit("babies")
```

I was having the same problem and this worked.

Comment: where am I supposed to put that at?

Answer (score -3):

Use na.omit() on the data set before running the lm function.

```
library(UsingR)
head(babies)

na.omit(babies)
m <- lm(wt ~ gestation + age + wt1 + dage + dwt, data=babies)
summary(m)
```

It will remove all he rows having NA values in them.